# adding mysql table values

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table in my database that holds numerical values collected from a user's input. How could I add those values together and display that number on the website, with the number updating every time a new number is inputed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would query a master table of IDs that has the running total of values.

Then, via any inserts into some alternate table that keeps each individual entry accounted for, there is a trigger that forces a SQL-Update to the master table... This way, you don't have to keep doing a web-based query that is always doing a GROUP BY for the results.

If this is a little confusing, think of an inventory system.  You have one master item table of all possible inventory items.  It has an "on hand" count.  Then, as sales of an item are sold, the "on hand" count is reduced by however many are purchased.  You are not going to each individual sales order and counting grouped by a given ID, you just go to thee master inventory item table and have that "on hand" count.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM table
```

Something like this? You should also look into [GROUP BY.](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php)

---

EDIT:

It could be you're meaning that you have a value and you want to increment it by n. Then you can look at this example code.

```
UPDATE table SET value = value + n WHERE id = 123
```

Where n is the value you want to increment it by.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in mysql so I wouldn't be exactly sure how to implement it. I'm trying to built a counter where you enter a value and it adds it to the previously added values. Currently, I  have a column called "hours" in my table. So I'm trying to add all the values in the column "hours". Does that make sense?

Comment: Not exactly. I want each new value to be added to the previous values. The value that is the result of the adding would then be echoed out to the webpage.